# How can I see which options are available in a RegexOptions enum?

Tags: regex, powershell, enums

How to use this function from powershell script to perform a case insensitive match with using the `-cmatch` operator:

```
static System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match Match(
     string input, 
     string pattern,
     System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions options)
```

I'm thinking its something like this:

```
PS>  $input = "one two three"

PS>  $m = [regex]::Match($input, "one", ????)
```

The part I have a question about is the `????` above.

How do you see what `System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions` are available from powershell prompt and what's the syntax to use it in the code above?

Answer (score 6):

The easy "cheat" way to see what options are available in an enum is to use tab completion within the PowerShell prompt or ISE. Start with `[System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::` and then use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>SPACE</kbd> (or <kbd>TAB</kbd>) to see the options.

The programmatic way, since `RegexOptions` is an enum, is this:

```
[System.Enum]::GetNames([System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions])
```

When you need to pass enum values in PowerShell, you can pass the long-form fully-qualified enum value (this is my preference):

```
[System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::IgnoreCase
```

Or you can pass the numeric value directly (`1`), or you can pass a string and it will be matched to the enum's text value `'IgnoreCase'`.

For your actual question: using `[regex]::Match()` is already case sensitive. You can just pass `[System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::None` to your call (or `0`, or `'None'`).

If you want it to be case-insensitive, then you use the `IgnoreCase` enum value as above.

Because this type of enum is a series of bit flags, you can combine them. To do that you use the `-bor` (bitwise or, or binary or) operator:

```
$myOptions = [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::IgnoreCase -bor 
        [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::SingleLine -bor
        [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::IgnorePatternWhitespace
```

But PowerShell's convenient coercion of strings to enums doesn't stop at single values. As [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) reminded me, you can comma separate the enum names within a string and PowerShell will *still* correctly parse it.

So you can use a string like `'IgnoreCase, SingleLine, IgnorePatternWhitespace'` directly when you need to pass in `RegexOptions`. You can also pre-cast it:

```
$myOptions = 'IgnoreCase, SingleLine, IgnorePatternWhitespace' -as [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]
$myOptions = [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]'IgnoreCase, SingleLine, IgnorePatternWhitespace'
```

Comment: whoops.  I think I accidently wrote case sensitive instead of insensitive.  But, you answer helps enough that I can figure it out.  thanks.

Comment: @BillMoore note that `-cmatch` is case-_sensitive_ and `-imatch` is case-_insensitive_ so you may have got the operators reversed as well. Anyway I added some more info to the answer about how to do either.

Answer (score 1):

Simplifying braintist answer a little bit to use namespaces:

```
PS> using namespace System.Text.RegularExpressions

PS> [Enum]::GetNames([RegexOptions])
None
IgnoreCase
Multiline
ExplicitCapture
Compiled
Singleline
IgnorePatternWhitespace
RightToLeft
ECMAScript
CultureInvariant

PS>  $input = "one two three"

PS>  $m = [regex]::Match($input, "one", [RegexOptions]::IgnoreCase)
```

Comment: Just a few things: `using` is only available in PowerShell v5+ so be aware of that. To avoid _typing_ as much (but still end up with longer code), you can tab complete full class names. So for example typing `[RegexO` and then hitting TAB will tab complete the entire fully-qualified class name (this is what I usually do).

Comment: @briantist It should be noted that tab completion can also be *absurdly* slow.  I've tried tab completion when I couldn't remember the spelling of a class had it take so long to finish that after pressing tab I had enough time to Google the name of the class, find it on MSDN, open a new PowerShell instance, and instance the class in the new window before it finished.

Comment: @BaconBits yeah that's true. Most of the time it works ok for me. Occasionally it does weird things, times out for no apparent reason, etc. (especially in ISE). But it's reliable enough for me  `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`